# How to write for comprehension in cats with IO monad

Tags: scala, scala-cats, cats-effect

I have the following code:

```
import cats.effect.IO
import cats.data.State
import cats.data.StateT
import cats.implicits._
import cats.effect.LiftIO

abstract class Example {
    object implicits {
        implicit def myEffectLiftIO: LiftIO[IOGameplay] =
            new LiftIO[IOGameplay] {
                override def liftIO[A](ioa: IO[A]): IOGameplay[A] = {
                    StateT.liftF(ioa)
                }
            }
    }

    type Gameplay[A] = State[GameState, A]
    type IOGameplay[A] = StateT[IO, GameState, A]
    type EitherDirection[A] = Either[Throwable, A]

    type Map = Array[Array[FieldType]]
    sealed trait FieldType
    case class GameState(map: Map, block: Block)
    case class Block(f1: Field, f2: Field) 
    case class Field()

    import implicits._
    val L = implicitly[LiftIO[IOGameplay]]

    sealed trait GameResult
    sealed trait Direction

    trait IOMonad {
        def println(msg: String): IO[Unit]
        def readln(): IO[String]
    }

    def play(io: IOMonad): StateT[IO, GameState, GameResult] = {
        val L = implicitly[LiftIO[IOGameplay]]

        for {
            // print map to the console
            _ <- L.liftIO(io.println("Next move: "))
            directionOpt <- L.liftIO(readDirection(io))
            direction <- StateT.liftF[IO, GameState, Direction](IO.fromEither(directionOpt))
            nextBlock <- IO(nextBlock(direction))
            gameResult <- calculate(nextBlock)
        } yield {
            gameResult
        }
    }

    def readDirection(io: IOMonad): IO[EitherDirection[Direction]]
    def nextBlock(direction: Direction): Gameplay[Block]
    def calculate(block: Block): Gameplay[GameResult]
}
```

This is not completely accurate, but I posted the whole block to explain the problem.
Here, I have many transformations on values to produce IO and to transform it to StateT. Is there a more clever way to do this? Maybe I should somehow separate io tasks from the main algorithm, i.e. from this for-comprehension? Or should I do it like this?

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you posted a complete example. Instead of posting a snippet from your actual code (that leaves much space for interpretation, for example `L`) I would suggest creating a small example program (e.g. in [scalafiddle](https://scalafiddle.io/)) that compiles successfully.

Comment: @MarkusAppel I posted the whole code. It won't compile because of for-comprehension in the play method, which is actually the subject of my question. I would be very thankful if you could give me advice on any other thing that could be improved as well.

Comment: That looks much better, now people will have a much easier time figuring out the problem. Thanks for listening to the advice. :)

Answer (score 0):

One issue is that your `Gameplay` type is not compatible with `IOGameplay`, since `Gameplay` uses the `Eval` monad. I assume you want this:

```scala
    type Gameplay[F[_], A] = StateT[F, GameState, A]
    type IOGameplay[A] = Gameplay[IO, A]
```

These methods need to return `IOGameplay` instances (or you could lift them in your program later):

```scala
    def nextBlock(direction: Direction): IOGameplay[Block]
    def calculate(block: Block): IOGameplay[GameResult]
```

Then the for-comprehension compiles with minor adjustments:

```scala
      for {
        // print map to the console
        _ <- L.liftIO(io.println("Next move: "))
        directionOpt <- L.liftIO(readDirection(io))
        direction <- StateT.liftF[IO, GameState, Direction](IO.fromEither(directionOpt))
        nextBlock <- nextBlock(direction)
        gameResult <- calculate(nextBlock)
      } yield {
        gameResult
      }
```

BTW, what is the intended purpose of the `IO` effect in this program? User input?

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to avoid lifting stuff from one monad to the other, then you can make your methods and interfaces polymorphic so that they can work with different monads and not just IO. Here's how to do that for your `IOMonad` trait:

```scala
  trait IOMonad[F[_]] {
    def println(msg: String): F[Unit]
    def readln(): F[String]
  }
```

The idea is to not commit to any specific monad, but to make things work for any monad that provides the features that you need for a specific use case. In the `IOMonad` example, we need the ability to run synchronous side effects, so we express that by passing a parameter of type `Sync[F]`:

```scala
import cats.effect.Sync
object IOMonad {
  def apply[F[_]](implicit F: Sync[F]) = new IOMonad[F] {
    def println(msg: String): F[Unit] = F.delay(println(msg))
    def readln(): F[String] = F.delay(scala.io.StdIn.readLine())
  }
}
```

The other operations in your program need different capabilities. For instance `readDirection` needs to do console IO and raise errors of type `Throwable`. The ability to raise errors is expressed by the `MonadError` trait, so you get this signature:

```scala
def readDirection[F[_]](
  io: IOMonad[F])(implicit monErr: MonadError[F, Throwable]
): F[Direction]
```

It's important to note that we're not passing a `Sync[F]` here, because we don't need it; the `IOMonad[F]` object is enough. This is important because it allows you to implement the `IOMonad` interface in some other way that doesn't necessarily involve side effects, notably for testing.

Another example are `nextBlock` and `calculate`. These need manipulate a state of type `GameState`, and the ability to manipulate state is expressed by the `MonadState` type:

```scala
def nextBlock[F[_]](
  direction: Direction)(implicit F: MonadState[F, GameState]
): F[Block]

def calculate[F[_]](
  block: Block)(implicit F: MonadState[F, GameState]
): F[GameResult]
```

`MonadState` is unfortunately not contained in cats or cats-effect, you need the `cats-mtl` library for that.

When you put all this together, you end up with a program like this:

```scala
import cats.MonadError
import cats.mtl.MonadState
import cats.implicits._

abstract class Example {
  type Map = Array[Array[FieldType]]
  sealed trait FieldType
  case class GameState(map: Map, block: Block)
  case class Block(f1: Field, f2: Field)
  case class Field()

  sealed trait GameResult
  sealed trait Direction

  trait IOMonad[F[_]] {
    def println(msg: String): F[Unit]
    def readln(): F[String]
  }

  def play[F[_]](
    io: IOMonad[F])(
    implicit merr: MonadError[F, Throwable],
    mst: MonadState[F, GameState]
  ): F[GameResult] = {
    for {
      // print map to the console
      _ <- io.println("Next move: ")
      direction <- readDirection(io)
      nextBlock <- nextBlock[F](direction)
      gameResult <- calculate[F](nextBlock)
    } yield gameResult
  }

  def readDirection[F[_]](
    io: IOMonad[F])(
    implicit merr: MonadError[F, Throwable]
  ): F[Direction]

  def nextBlock[F[_]](
    direction: Direction)(
    implicit merr: MonadState[F, GameState]
  ): F[Block]

  def calculate[F[_]](
    block: Block)(
    implicit mst: MonadState[F, GameState]
  ): F[GameResult]
}
```

Note that every single concrete Monad is gone – there is no `IO`, no `State`, no `Either` in the above program, and together with these, any necessity to convert or lift between different monads also went away.

Note however that this style of programming (known as MTL-Style) has its drawbacks.

- type inference often doesn't work. In this example you need to pass the `F` parameter explicitly to `nextBlock` and `calculate`, because Scala can't infer it
- as mentioned before, cats doesn't include all the necessary type classes like `MonadState`, so you need additional libraries like `cats-mtl`
- it's somewhat hard to understand for newcomers

This is why parts of the Scala community (notably John de Goes and his ZIO effort) are no longer encouraging MTL-style. Others keep pushing it, because it allows code to be reused with different effect types.